# echo line returns in html source code

Tags: php, html

How do you implement line returns when the html code is between simple quotes. The only way I found is to concatenate the line return between double quotes:

```
echo '<div>'."\n"
    .'<h3>stuff</h3>'."\n" 
    .'</div>'."\n";
```

Which lucks ugly to me.

**Edit:** The code between the simple quotes is quite long and with many attributes otherwise I would just use double quotes.

Comment: Is there a reason to echo? Can't you just get out of php, spit out what you need and then back into php?

Comment: It's a portion of code that will be repeated many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
echo "<div>\n<h3>stuff</h3>\n</div>\n";
```

or

```
echo '<div>
    <h3>stuff</h3>
</div>
';
```

Comment: The second example is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
echo "<div>\n" .
    "<h3>stuff</h3>\n" .
    "</div>\n";
```

or

```
echo "<div>
    <h3>stuff</h3>
    </div>\n";
```

or

```
echo <<< HTML
    <div>
        <h3>stuff</h3>
    </div>
HTML;
```

But this is completely subjective.

Comment: Thanks, where can I find info about that last notation. What is it called ?

Comment: @DrDro It's the Heredoc notation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php -- it's a bit ugly IMO, but it avoids the quotation escaping problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation: echo `'<div>' . "n";`

Concatenation with constant: `echo '<div>' . PHP_EOL;`

Hard line feeds:

```
echo '<div>
';
```

End PHP mode: `echo '<div>'; ?>`

Double quotes: `echo "<div>\n";`

Heredoc:

```
echo <<<EOM
    <div>

EOM;
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes inhibit backslash sequences. But newlines are pretty much optional outside of CDATA sections, so feel free to omit them.

Comment: I would want to had te line returns for the readability of the html source code

Comment: Well, technically newlines are just unnecessary whitespace (=bandwidth), but he obviously cares about the look of the output's source code.

Comment: @Alan I'm not against optimisation at all but my final page weights about 48k with empty cache so I'm not to worried about a few more whitespaces. I agree adding line returns in the html is arguable but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @DrDro I didn't say it's a bad thing. I like properly formatted source code as much as the next guy. I was just pointing out that it wasn't just out of standards compliance you wanted those newlines there.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo <<<EOM
<div>
<h3 class="blabla" style='booboo' >stuff<h3>
</div>

EOM;
```

Using the <<< quotation, you don't need to escape any characters(they are simply outputted exactly how they are typed.